# Effect of CO2 on the environment, besides greenhouse effect and ocean acidification

Tags: geophysics, atmospheric-science

What effects does the raising level of CO2 in the atmosphere have, besides being a greenhouse gas and responsible for the increased acidity of the oceans?

What other environmental damages does it cause?

Comment: Contributes to acid rain, poisons aerobic respirators (unless they also produce oxygen). Anyone else have more?

Comment: @Jim: I am not sure it poisons aerobic respirators, maybe it suffocates them in a closer room, which is not part of the question.

Comment: True, I misspoke. It poisons blood and other oxygen-carrying media. Not all aerobic respirators.

Comment: This is a good question for the new [Earthscience.SE] stack exchange, that should hopefully reach public beta soon.

Comment: @Jim you are confusing dioxide with monoxide, which last is a poison. CO2 is plant food and we exude something like 10000ppm in our exhalation though the process of oxygen exchange in the lungs. It is not dangerous unless in a closed room with no oxygen. The biosphere has survived with thousands ppm CO2 at various palaiontoligical ages.

Comment: I think this question needs to be more specific. Are you asking what physical effects (measurable) CO2-concentration has on the atmosphere?

Answer (score 2):

As CO2 increases, the photosynthesis rate in plants generally increases.  The degree of the effect is species dependent.  See [Effects of Rising Atmospheric Concentrations of Carbon Dioxide on Plants](http://www.nature.com/scitable/knowledge/library/effects-of-rising-atmospheric-concentrations-of-carbon-13254108).

Comment: Right. It is a necessary part of life, if CO2 falls in the atmosphere  below 150ppm plants die. Real green houses keep their atmosphere artificially at 1000ppm for fast growth.